# javascript set id attribute into option not working

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, select

I've got problem with set id into  , after set in inspector i didn't see id attribute ...

First way JS:

```js
var selectorElem = document.getElementById('selector')
var optElem = document.createElement('option');
optElem.id = "750-2"
selectorElem.appendChild(optElem)
```

```html
<div className="form-group">
  <select className="form-control" id="selector" />
</div>
```

and second way JS which too not working:

```js
var selectorElem = document.getElementById('selector')
var optElem = document.createElement('option');
optElem.setAttribute("id", "750-2")
selectorElem.appendChild(optElem)
```

```html
<div className="form-group">
  <select className="form-control" id="selector" />
</div>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I made your code runnable. They both have ids on the option it created when I inspected it in the console.

Comment: So why i don't have id attribute in console? Maybe it's other cause

Comment: I see the attribute in Chrome. I am not sure why you are unable to see it.

Answer (score -1):

setAttribute is working for me

```
var optElem = document.createElement('option');
optElem.setAttribute('id', '750-2')
console.log(optElem.id) //Output -> "750-2"
```